# How to mock location using google's FusedLocationProviderClient

Tags: android, testing, location, android-espresso

I am working on Espresso UI Testing, When I request the location using FusedLocationProviderClient I turned the testing state to idle when I tried to mock the location using setMockLocation(Location mockLocation) method I did not get the LocationCallback get called.